# Adding doctype html breaks layout height

Tags: css, html

I was developing a page recently, and after finding that everything worked properly noticed that I hadn't added the `<!doctype html>` tag at the top.  Upon adding it, the layout ignored the height.

I stripped it down to the most basic layout to see what was wrong and the problem persists.  Is what I'm doing inconsistent with HTML5?

[The working source code](http://pastebin.com/5JsZVLyV)

[What it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gprG.jpg)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should add the code to your post or it will get closed. Also, something on codepen or jsfiddle would work better, so that we can actually see the results, rather than pastebin.

Add this to your CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%; /* for firefox */
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  It works as desired. 

I'll also keep jsfiddle in mind the next time that I post.

Comment: Thank you for this.  Old answer but still relevant.

Comment: This answer is still relevant. Thank you @Xarcell for this answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the height of your  tag

```
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```